# how to split the data in a column based on multiple delimiters, into multiple columns, in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with only one column named 'ALL_category[![enter image description here][1]][1]'. There are multiple names in a row ranging between 1 to 3 and separated by delimiters '|', '||' or '|||', which can be either at the beginning, in between or end of the words in every row. I want to split the column into multiple columns such that the new columns contain the names. How can I do it?

Below is the code to generate the dataframe:

```
x = {'ALL Categories': ['Rakesh||Ramesh|','||Rajesh|','HARPRIT|||','Tushar||manmit|']}
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

When I used the below code for modification of the above dataframe, it didn't give me any result.

```
data = data.ALL_HOLDS.str.split(r'w', expand = True)
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: `df['ALL_Category'].str.split(r'\|+', expand=True)` ..?

Comment: @jezrael: will take care of that in the future

Comment: What do you think that regex does?

Comment: @jezrael: i modified to include the code for getting the df.

Comment: @AM - Super, can you add expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) if want each word to separate column:

```
df1 = df['ALL Categories'].str.extractall(r'(\w+)')[0].unstack()
print (df1)
match        0       1
0       Rakesh  Ramesh
1       Rajesh     NaN
2      HARPRIT     NaN
3       Tushar  manmit
```

Or a bit changed code of @Chris A from comments with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by one or more `|`:

```
df1 = df['ALL Categories'].str.strip('|').str.split(r'\|+', expand=True)
print (df1)
         0       1
0   Rakesh  Ramesh
1   Rajesh    None
2  HARPRIT    None
3   Tushar  manmit
```